# Usage of "figure" and "figure out"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Sometimes I get confused whether to use *figure* or *figure out*.

Example:

> Cynthia didn't blame his dad for being so quiet. She just figured (out) some fathers
>   found it more difficult to communicate with their daughters than
>   others.

I'm not sure which one I should use. Is there a way of knowing when to use the first and when the latter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> She just figured some fathers...

In this case *just* is synonymous with *simply*.

> She just figured out some fathers...

In this case *just* is synonymous with *very recently*.

*Figure* tends to mean *realised* or *thought*.

*Figure out* tends to mean *solve*.

Comment: Although it sounds like "figured out" is more akin to "found out" than "solved" and should be followed by a "that" in your second example. (could be personal preference).

Comment: @userNaN I would say the the *that* is optional.

Answer (score 4):

**to figure** means :

- to appear, rather conspicuously
- to represent (on a paper, in imagination, etc.)
- to ascertain (US-English)

**to figure out** means :

- to work out by mathematics
- to estimate
- to understand

**to figure on** is US-English, meaning to expect, to count upon

*In your example, it means that she realized (and admitted) that ...*